# Routing to a new page for each search result with React?

Tags: reactjs, api, routes

I'm really new to React and I'm working on this webapp, where I managed to receive data from the Google Books API and managed to list the results when I search for it.

How do I make a new page for each book whenever the user clicks on one of the books?

The code looks like this so far:

```
  renderSearchResults = () => {
const { results } = this.state;

if (Object.keys(results).length && results.length) {
  return (
    <div className='results-container'>
      {results.map((result) => {
        return (
          <a
            key={result.id}
            href={result.previewLink}
            className='result-item'
          >
            <div className='image-wrapper'>
              <a href={result.volumeInfo.infoLink}>
                <img
                  className='image'
                  src={result.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail}
                  alt={result.volumeInfo.infoLink}
                />
              </a>
            </div>
            <h6 className='image-title'>{result.volumeInfo.title}</h6>
          </a>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

};

Right now I made it so that when each book is clicked it will redirect to the Google page for each book, but I want to make it like the design below, where when the user clicks they will be redirected to a new page like this:

[The design I want to develop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQSSa.png)

Let me know if you have a solution or if you need any other information in order to help me.

Other than that, have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Exist in html the target Attribute, u can use like this:

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools</a>
```

for more information [see this w3schools.com definition](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)